# Is this file object left open?

Tags: java, file, try-with-resources

As an exercise for school I wrote a method in Java that searches for a character in a file. Here is the code:

```
 public static void countLetter(char needle, String hayStack) throws IOException {

        File f = new File(hayStack);                                           
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(f)) {                                    
            String str = null;                                                 
            while (in.hasNext()){                                              
                str += in.next();                                              
            }                                                                  
            char[] charArr = str.toCharArray();                                
            int counter = 0;                                                   
            for (char c: charArr) {                                            
                if (c == needle){                                              
                    counter++;                                                 
                }                                                              
            }                                                                  
            System.out.println(counter);                                       
        }                                                                      
    }
```

This does what I need it to but I have a question. **Is the file object ever opened? And if it is, does it ever closed?** I used try-with-resources on the Scanner object so I'm pretty sure I don't have to explicitly close that, but what about the file object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File object is just an abstract representation of a pathname, it has nothing to do with opening a file. So it can not be closed.

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752266/why-java-io-file-doesnt-have-a-close-method

Comment: I think your onto something here.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is what it boils down to. Thanks for your perspective Mukesh.

Answer (score 1):

The `File` object can not be opened (and therefore can not be closed) as it is a representation of a file path and not a representation of a file.

The `Scanner` class opens your file in order to read it. Your program doesn't call `in.close()` so when your method returns the `Scanner` will not be garbage collected as it still has a reference to an open file. You may also be locking the file depending on how the file was opened by the `Scanner`.

In order for a class to qualify for automatically closing resources in a try-resource block the class must implement `java.lang.AutoCloseable` (or `java.io.Closeable`). `Scanner` does not implement these interfaces and so it won't have its `close()` method called when you exit the try-resource block.

Alter the code to:

```
public static void countLetter(char needle, String hayStack) throws IOException {

    File f = new File(hayStack);                                           
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(f)) {                                    
        String str = null;                                                 
        while (in.hasNext()){                                              
            str += in.next();                                              
        }                                                                  
        char[] charArr = str.toCharArray();                                
        int counter = 0;                                                   
        for (char c: charArr) {                                            
            if (c == needle){                                              
                counter++;                                                 
            }                                                              
        }                                                                  
        System.out.println(counter);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version are you looking at "Scanner.java:348", it's a comment line on mine. You might be referring to a section in the comments that says the scanner will close Closable's but you have to call close first as Scanner is itself *not* Closeable. The file opened inside the Scanner is not in scope and so won't be closed when you exit the try-resource block.

Answer (score 0):

As the variable is local to your function so it will go out of scope once the function exists, and eventually garbage collection. Answer to your question is NO, in your case file object is not ever opened.

Comment: I don't think it's good to rely on contingencies to close files. I could be mistaken.

Comment: Ideally you should close it.