# Why does java.io.File not implement Autocloseable?

Tags: java

After upgrading to Java 7 I get the following code flagged by Eclipse:

```
    try (File file = new File(FILE_NAME)) {
        file.delete();          
    }
```

Error is:

> The resource type File does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable

And Java's documentation doesn't have File listed in the AutoCloseable docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

So besides adding the catch block, what is the suggested alternative?

Comment: File isn't actually a file, it's a file path.  There's nothing to close.

Comment: What do you think `close()` in File should do and when should it be used?

Comment: I see, face palm! Fell victim to the idiotic naming conventions in the Java library. Found this later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752266/why-java-io-file-doesnt-have-a-close-method

Comment: "*Fell victim to the idiotic naming conventions in the Java library*" that is why you should start using nio (new IO) and combinations of `Files` and `Path` (now path gives clearer idea that we are dealing with paths, not with actual content of file, doesn't it?). It is more intuitive and gives us less chances to made mistakes. Consider reading http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks and http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API

Comment: @Pshemo its really too bad that File is used to represent a File Directory item. It breaks all mental models. I will try to remember, thanks.

Comment: @SalvadorValencia Yes, Java has few places where names could be misleading, for instance `Runnable` should be called `Task`, because we are not actually using it to run things, but we are describing task which should be executed by Thread. Also `Arrays.asList` return instance of `ArrayList` but not `java.utli.ArrayList`, but inner static class for `Arrays` utility class. IMO it should be called something like `ArrayWrapperList` to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Jeffrey said in the comment to the question, you need to differentiate between a File and an InputStream, e.g. FileInputStream.
There is nothing to close in a File, but there is something to close in a stream or a reader.

```
try (FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream (new File(FILE_NAME))) {
    // do what you want with the stream
}
```