# Iterating files in scala/java in O(1) open file descriptors

Tags: java, scala, nio

It appears that nio's `.list` returns a stream which when consumed, holds on to one file descriptor per file iterated, until `.close` is called on the entire stream. This means that data directories with upwards of 1,000 files can easily brush against common `ulimit` values. The overall effect of this file descriptor accumulation, further exacerbates when dealing with nested traversals.

What might be an alternative way to iterate over the files of large directories, other than going down to spawning calls to the OS file list command? It would be cool if iterating the files of a large directory, a file descriptor would be maintained only per the currently iterated file, as implied by proper stream semantics.

Edit:

`list` returns a java Stream of `java.nio.file.Path` Which api call would be used for closing each item on the stream once it's been processed, rather than only when the entire stream is being closed, for leaner iteration? In scala, this can be easily fiddled using the api wrapper from better-files, leading from [here](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files/blob/1c6f0f05d2aa3e16ddb06c0b275d0da9372fa7b0/core/src/main/scala/better/files/File.scala#L236).

Comment: "holds on to one file descriptor per file iterated, until .close is called on the entire stream" How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: I came to that conclusion by counting file descriptors through JMX (Scala 2.11 on Oracle java 8, on Ubuntu), before and after iterating the result of `.list`, with and without calling `close` after the iteration.

Comment: Had same problem with custom RDD in Spark. Added a list of open connections and a  close () method to close all open connections at the end. Maybe you could modify the iterator code to close a file already streamed.

Comment: the Spark scenario sounds interesting @VincenzoMaggio. I could try that kind of fiddling when I context switch back. Let's see what else comes up... :) maybe a different IO library that's a better fit.

Comment: Looks like a `Path` returned from `list` [has no `close` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4752280/1509695), so I'm probably a little confused about how to close a file, or, where is a file descriptor actually being created so that it can be closed while iterating the stream, rather than only when the stream depletes.

Comment: I think you should show your iteration code.  I'm assuming you're talking about `Files.list` here, which returns a `Stream<Path>`.  There's nothing in the documentation to suggest that doing this should open the file unless you do it yourself in the consumer.

Comment: Agreed, I will come back here to post code that shows the accumulation. Mind you, that we are talking about open file descriptors ― I am not entirely certain about whether that is synonymous with opening a file. But their count costs the OS and is limited by `ulimit`. Understanding how do nio file operations map to file descriptor allocation may seem elusive.

Comment: Somehow I cannot reproduce it, please ignore this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue (on Windows Server 2012 R2) when I didn't close the stream. All the files I iterated over were open in read mode until the JVM was shut down. However, it did not occur on Mac OS X and since the stream depends on OS-dependent implementations of `FileSystemProvider` and `DirectoryStream`, I assume the issue can be OS-dependent, too.

Contrary to the @Ian McLaird comment, it is mentioned in the [`Files.list()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-) documentation that

> If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

The returned stream is a `DirectoryStream`, whose Javadoc says:

> A DirectoryStream is opened upon creation and is closed by invoking the close method. Closing a directory stream releases any resources associated with the stream. Failure to close the stream may result in a resource leak.

My solution was to follow the advice and use the `try-with-resources` construct

```
try (Stream<Path> fileListing = Files.list(directoryPath)) {
    // use the fileListing stream
}
```

When I closed the stream properly (used the above `try-with-resources` construct), the file handles were immediately released.

If you don't care about getting the files as a stream or you are OK with loading the whole file list into memory and convert it to a stream yourself, you can use the IO API:

```
File directory = new File("/path/to/dir");
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
if (files != null) { // 'files' can be null if 'directory' "does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."
    // use the 'files' array or convert to a stream:
    Stream<File> fileStream = Arrays.stream(files);
}
```

I did not experience any file-locking issues with this one. However, note that both solutions rely on native, OS-dependent code, so I advise testing in all environments you would be using.

Comment: Why didn't you suffice with just closing the stream in your case? you seem to echo my experience in which a file handler was taken (and accumulated) per file iterated, which I later couldn't reproduce.

Comment: Although my question was sort of a non-question, because, I could not reproduce that file handlers were taken by just iterating the directory, I am awarding the bounty here as this answer seems to shed the most light on the overall matter, perhaps usefully for other cases / searches as well. Also I am very grateful for the panoramic and research oriented answer.

Comment: @matanster: thanks for appreciation! I'm not sure if we understood each other correctly - initially I **did not** close the stream and ran into the same issue as you did. When I used the `try-with-resources` construct **it helped** and the file handles were immediately released (but only after closing the stream). I edited the answer to emphasize that. I was developing on Mac OS X where this issue did not occur, but when I deployed to Win Server 2012 R2, it happened.

Answer (score 4):

If that happens why not to use old school java.io.File?

```
File folder = new File(pathToFolder);
String[] files = folder.list();
```

tested with `lsof` and it looks like no of the listed files is open. You can convert the array to a list or stream afterwards. Unless the directory is too large or remote, then I would try to blame Path objects and garbage-collect or somehow destroy them.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the Apache FileUtils library, which use the old 
java.io.File.listFiles function internaly :

```
Iterator<File> it = FileUtils.iterateFiles(folder, null, true);
while (it.hasNext())
{
   File fileEntry = (File) it.next();
}
```