# Replace an existing file, length issue

Tags: java, android, file, stream

I have a strange issue, when replacing a file by another.
This code works well the first time :

```
String fileContent = "test";    

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myApp/text.txt");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

        bufferedOutputStream.write(fileContent.getBytes());

        bufferedOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It creates a file with this content :

```
test
```

Then I execute the code again, replacing the "test" string by a longer string :

```
String fileContent = "admiral";
```

It removes the old file, create a new one, BUT it only write the 4 first characters :

```
admi
```

Finally, if I replace the content by a shorter string ("be", it creates a corrupted file :

```
be\00\00
```

But if I remove the file manually, it works... Very strange...

**SOLVED : The problem was, gedit's cache! :s, by the way thx all for your help ! :)**

Comment: have you tried adding `bufferedOutputStream.flush()` after `write`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to overwrite the content using this :

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to use `BufferedOutputStream`...
Just try to write using `FileOutputStream` in this way:

```
String fileContent = "test";    
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myApp/text.txt");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

        fileOutputStream.write(fileContent.getBytes());

        fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Reference: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016278/is-this-the-best-way-to-rewrite-the-content-of-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

First be aware that `String.getBytes()` without the optional parameter for the charset, takes that of the current platform.

For appending one would need to call:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
```

In your case you want to replace the contents, and your construct does that already. Remove `delete` as that gives better system behavior.

Then the final problem writing only 4 bytes.

```
   bufferedOutputStream.write(fileContent.getBytes());
```

As if the old file length (of "test" = 4 bytes) was used to write the new content. I cannot explain that, so maybe the removal of `delete` might cause the bug to disappear.

What might be the case, is that the file is opened elsewhere.